# BufferedReader read(char[], int, int) blocked?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am reading from a `BufferedReader`, which is wrapping an `InputStreamReader`. The stream comes from a URL with `myURL.openStream();`

I am trying to read a portion of the stream (characters between `startPos` and `endPos`) into a `String` and then store it in a text file.

```
    char[] buffer = new char[endPos-startPos];
    reader.skip(startPos);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < (endPos-startPos)){
        buffer[i] = (char) reader.read();
        i++;
    }
```

The above code works, but seems pretty slow.
I am trying to use the `read(char[], int, int)` method instead - I assume the Java people have implemented it quicker!

However - it gets about halfway through adding the desired characters into the string then finishes, leaving me with a half full char array.

According to Javadoc it only does this when it either reaches EOF, or "The ready method of the underlying stream returns false, indicating that further input requests would block". Can anyone tell me what this means? And why is it happening if reading the characters one by one works fine? (Can't be EOF!)

Comment: Why do you think that reading an array is much faster for a buffered reader? It's buffered!

Comment: Why not just say `< length`? Instead of `endPos - startPos` .. sheesh

Comment: How much time does it take to read the url? You should expect high latency to IO ops such as this

Comment: Do you mean you're just calling `read` once? Please show us the code.

Comment: Instead of this part:

    int i = 0;
    while(i < (endPos-startPos)){
        buffer[i] = (char) reader.read();
        i++;
    }

Comment: I want to do this

reader.read(buff, 0, endPos-startPos);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slow because the data is arriving slowly. Nothing you can do about that in the receiving code. `read(char[] ...)` returns prematurely because only that many bytes arrived after the first read blocked. If you want to read a specific number of characters you have to loop, either calling `read()` or `read(char[], ...)`. As `BufferedReader` is, err, buffered, it won't make any difference which one you call.